# How to prevent other elements changing, when changing style of element with same class

Tags: javascript, dom

I am moving individual elements around using their style.top and style.left attributes. The issue is that when changing the style of one element it seems to change the style of others. What is an effective way to get round this?

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this happens, but I guess you selected the element by using a .class selector. Please make sure to select only one element. If you add / edit style-rules of that element, it does not change other elements sharing the element's classname.

Comment: I am creating the elements with document.createElement() and keeping track of the individual objects

Comment: Does the position of those other elements depend on the one you are moving around?